# Ble with record video

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

I'm working on rpi3.
When I try to run the command:

```
sudo ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -video_size 640x480 -r 25 output.avi
```

to record a video using ffmpeg.

In this time,I try to connect with Bluetooth.

The BT cannot connect.

the exception I get is:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

top result:

```
1156 root 20 0 299860 197172 137736 S 80.6 20.9 40:21.35 ffmpeg
```

80.6 % cpu and 20.9 % mem.

all the other processes take less than 1%.

Did you encounter with this?
Do you have a clue what can be done?

Thanks